# App build.gradle.kts File Unresolved Reference Erros

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

i have a build.gradle.kts file in my Appfolder.

```
import org.gradle.internal.impldep.com.amazonaws.PredefinedClientConfigurations.defaultConfig



buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        configurations {
           classpath ("com.github.shyiko:ktlint:0.11.1")
        }

        classpath ("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha01")
        classpath ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${"kotlin_version"}")


    }  
}

plugins {
    id ("org.jmailen.kotlinter") version "1.5.0"
    id ("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt") version "1.0.0.RC5-3"

}

apply { from ("com.android.application") }
apply { from ( "kotlin-android" ) }
apply { from ( "kotlin-android-extensions" )}


android {
    compileSdkVersion ("28")
    buildToolsVersion ("27.0.0")

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}

ext {
    ankoVersion = "0.10.2"

    moshiVersion = "1.5.0"
    okioVersion = "1.13.0"
    okhttpVersion = "3.8.1"
    okhttpUrlconnectionVersion = "${okhttpVersion}"
    okhttpAndroidSupportVersion = "${okhttpVersion}"
    okhttpLoggingInterceptorVersion = "${okhttpVersion}"
    retrofitVersion = '2.3.0'
    retrofitMoshiVersion = "${retrofitVersion}"

    robolectricVersion = '3.5.1'
    robolectricAndroidAllVersion = '8.1.0-robolectric-r4402310'

    kluentVersion = '1.30'
}





dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation ("com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout") version "1.1.0-beta3"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8" version ($kotlin_version)
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:$ankoVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:$moshiVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$moshiVersion"

    implementation "com.squareup.okio:okio:$okioVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttpVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:$okhttpUrlconnectionVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-android-support:$okhttpAndroidSupportVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttpLoggingInterceptorVersion"
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion") {
        exclude module: "okhttp"
    }
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$retrofitMoshiVersion"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:$robolectricVersion"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:android-all:$robolectricAndroidAllVersion"
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.3-alpha', {
        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-annotations"
    })
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation "org.amshove.kluent:kluent:$kluentVersion"
}

detekt {
    profile("main") {
        input = "$projectDir/src/main/kotlin"

    }
}
```

This is my complete build.gradle file.
The first Part from the top to android is , in my opion fine. Android Studio also shows no error.

But, starting with the Keyword Android {, every single line is flagged as an error.
i used this [page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html) to check how android should be implemented. But again this isn´t working for me. I guess i missunderstand the Docu or mix something up.

Comment: what is the reason to use kotlin-script and not traditional gradle - groovy? at the moment android gradle plugin is not ready for production, so you need to do this things step by step. Here is video step by step https://youtu.be/XLNJkxWoCoc?list=PLt8lEzcLNl33F_6cQqDpnWK1iR4fJC4zu&t=1269

Comment: Thx for the video link! it helped me.

Answer (score 2):

in `gradle` `compileSdkVersion` is `int` value and should looks like this

```
compileSdkVersion (28)
```

And i think you are mixed up `Project:gradle` and `Module:gradle`

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought. Thx for the help! :)